# Win Forms Dock fill with gap

Tags: c#, winforms

**Fore note:** I know you cannot use a margin with dock, but I am trying to figure a way around this.

I have two objects, a GroupBox (containing loads of buttons and stuff that will always be the same size no matter how big / small the form) and a WebBrowser. The former will take up roughly 100 pixels at the top, and the latter will take up the rest of the space. I have tried multiple ways to get around this, including Panels, GroupBoxs, changing Anchors and Docks, but nothing is working. I know there is a simple solution for this, but I cannot work it out. Could someone point me in the right direction for what I should be using?

P.S. New to WinForms so not very knowledgeable of things.

Comment: Just use the GroupBox Anchor Properties and the Webbrowser Docking Property

Comment: It is possible, set the Padding property on the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a **TableLayoutPanel** control on your Form and set its Dock() property to Fill.  Now change the ColumnCount() property to 1, and leave the RowCount() property at 2.

Add your GroupBox to the Top Row and adjust its size.  Add your WebBrowser control to the Bottom Row and set its Dock() property to Fill.

Finally, select the TableLayoutPanel, find the Rows() property, and click on the "..." dots to the right.  Select Row1 and change its Size Type to AutoSize.

Done!

*Alternative Approach...*

Add your GroupBox to the Form and set its Dock() property to Top.  Add your WebBrowser control and set its Dock() property to Fill.  Note with this approach, however, that the GroupBox will extend to fill the full width of the Form.

Comment: Much appreciated!